# Grommet min css file size is 393kb, can we reduce the size?

Tags: webpack, grommet

The grommet.min.css is 393kb, if i use the sass loader in webpack and import grommet index.scss, the bundle size increases by 468kb. Is there anyway to reduce this size?
  How can we include only the styles that are needed?

Thanks